# How do I test Application Controller methods with Shoulda?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

The closest resource I've found for testing things inside the application controller is [here](http://ridingtheclutch.com/post/25040810096/how-to-test-stuff-in-applicationcontroller-or).  Unfortunately, it doesn't actually work -- MyApp generates an uninitialized constant.  I've tried other methods of adding the appropriate route, but none of them work.

My purpose is to test the authentication methods I've imbedded into the ApplicationController -- I don't want to put the tests into other controllers, because that's not their concern.  It's something that supports them, but it's not part of 'their' functionality.
    require 'test_helper'

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def index; end
end

class AppControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  Rails.application.routes.draw do
    controller :test do
      get 'test/index' => :index
    end
  end

  setup do
    @controller = TestController.new
  end

  should "return nil if there is no district subdomain" do
    get :index
    assert_equal 'bar', @controller.send(:foo)
  end

end
```

The above code results in an url helper method error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"test"}
```

Edit:

Thanks to Boulder's kind advice, I moved past this, but his suggestion for fixing the routes after doesn't work:

```
teardown do
  Rails.application.reload_routes!
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's assuming that MyApp is the name of your application, which I doubt. You should change it and use the actual name of your application. Even better, do

```
    Rails.application.routes.append
      controller :test do
        get 'test/index' => :index
      end
    end
```

Comment: This is actually one of several patterns I tried, with no success.  Rails still can't connect the route to the test controller's method.  `ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"test"}`

Comment: You may need to show us your test. I can't help you without more information

Comment: Just occurred to me: use Rails.application.routes.draw, instead of append. In your teardown you probably want to do `Rails.application.reload_routes!` so everything goes back to normal

Comment: it's exactly like setup

Comment: Well, it's not working.  My routes remain affected, breaking other tests.